# Java Map stream

Tags: java, потоки-данных, map, filter

Есть 
`Map <String, <Person>> persons;`

Заполним

`persons.put('Коля', new Person("Коля", 15));`

`persons.put('Коля', new Person("Коля", 23));`

`persons.put('Вася', new Person("Коля", 15));`

Мне нужно с помощью Stream отфильтроваться и оставить только те ключи в map, которые повторяются, то есть только Коль

Comment: В `Map` невозможно сохранить дубликаты. Второй вызов `put` с ключом "Коля" затрёт первый. Фильтровать ничего не нужно.

Comment: Может, `Map<String, List<Person>>`?